# How to restrict the open AI API responses to only tech/software related? If user asks non tech question then say 'Not related'

Tags: api, openai-api

How to restrict the below open AI API to respond only to certain fields. For example **only software and tech related queries needs to be answered** otherwise it should respond with "**Not related to software and tech**". I know the API is generic and answers all the queries, but is there any other way it can be restricted ?

```
https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions
https://api.openai.com/v1/completions
```

Here is the query passed

```
const query = `first check this query '${sugg}' is related to software or not, if it is not related then reply with 'Not Related' otherwise provide some suggestions to that query`
  const data = {
    model: "text-davinci-002",
    prompt : query,
    top_p: 1,
    frequency_penalty: 0,
    presence_penalty: 0,
    max_tokens: 500,
    n: 1,
  };
```

Here `sugg` is the query passed based on the user input.

It is working but sometimes giving unwanted responses, how to prevent this or is there any other alternate method available to achieve this functionality.

I mean, if the user asks what is node js, then the response should be something related to node js, but if the user asks what is geography (which is not related to tech/software) then the response should be note related software. Hope u got the context of my question. How to achieve this kind of functionality with this API ? Is it possible ? or is there any other method to achieve this ?

Comment: What is an "unwanted response"? Please edit your question and add some details.

Comment: @RokBenko I mean, if the user asks what is node js, then the response should be something related to node js, but if the user asks what is geography (which is not related to tech/software) then the response should be note related software. Hope u got the context of my question. How to achieve this kind of functionality with this API ? Is it possible ? or is there any other method to achieve this ?

Comment: The code above doesn't do the job? It gives you an answer even to non-tech related questions?

Comment: Yeah sometimes giving non tech responses, but when I pass same query to  https://chat.openai.com/chat everything is working fine. But on calling API's there is some issues

Comment: Try to use a newer GPT-3 model (e.g., `text-davinci-003`). Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: @RokBenko I fixed it using the gpt-turbo-3.5, its all about using the correct "Prompt".